# ETW framework and .ETL log (string message encryption)

Tags: etw

If I am sending confidential info (like function name) to the **ETW** session. Can it be retrieved just by opening the **.etl** log in notepad++ or any other text editor ?

Comment: not via text editor but with other tools like xperfview, WPA.exe or PerfView which can decode ETL files. Why and which confidential info do you need to send?